# Not executing second query?

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, ms-access

When I click the button, only my first query gets executed. The second one `insert into afspraken (behandeling)` doesn't execute. Anybody knows why?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Afspraken (Afspraakdatum) VALUES ('" + textBox23.Text + "');";
    string insertStatement1 = "INSERT INTO Afspraken (Behandeling) VALUES ('" + textBox21.Text + "');";
    OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection);
    OleDbCommand insertCommand1 = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement1, connection);
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        textBox23.Clear();
        textBox21.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Uw afspraak is gemaakt!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I saw in your comments on another answer, I believe this solution would work best for you:

```
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Afspraken (Afspraakdatum, Behandeling) VALUES ('" + textBox23.Text + "', '" + textBox21.Text + "');");
OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection);
```

But remember that this code is unsafe, you should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your suggested code results in the following error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "30-01-2016, few;'.

Note that "30-01-2016" and "few" are my values from the textbox,

Comment: I have changed my answer, I was missing an apostrophe after the first value. Check it out now

Answer (score 2):

You're creating `insertCommand1`, but you're never executing it. You're only executing `insertCommand` (in the single line inside your `try` block).

Comment: Thank you. Overlooked it. But what happens now: they are put seperate in the acces database file. command and command 1 need to be put both on the same row in my database. Like : Date - Treatment